# Preferred way of writing CommonJS plugins for jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, commonjs

The latest jQuery v1 (as of now: v1.10.2) finally uses CommonJS.
This allows to use it as a node module, e.g. with [webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake).

**What is the preferred way of writing plugins for jQuery in a CommonJS compatible way?**

The following seems logical to me:

1. If CommonJS is not available fall back to other techniques (AMD, global objects)
2. Require jQuery like:

   ```
   var $ = require('jQuery');
   ```
3. Define new functions/objects (jQuery can be used with $)
4. Export those new functions/objects by assigning them to module.exports, e.g.:

   ```
   module.exports.newFunc = newFunc;
   ```

Should I do it that way? Are there good alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/umdjs/umd - this is a wrapper for both AMD and CommonJS.

Comment: For the records: This is what I am using now: https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/jqueryPluginCommonjs.js